# using perl to write unmatching elements between two files

Tags: perl

I'm getting in trouble with a simple thing. I need to compare two files and write only the patterns that don't match between the two.

My first file looks like this:

```
1 A A
2 A B
3 C D
4 E F
5 G H
6 I L
```

My second file looks like this:

```
A A
A B
C D
```

What do I want is to use the pair list in the second file to select the unmatching rows in the first file and print them in the output. My desired output looks like this:

```
4 E F
5 G H
6 I L
```

My code below needs improvements and I need your help to do that!

```
open (FUS, "< $file_1")|| die "Impossible open file 1";
@f = <FUS>;
close (FUS);

open (ALL, "< $file_2")|| die "Impossible open file 2";
@a = <ALL>;
close (ALL);

for ($c=0; $c<=$#a; $c++) {
    chomp ($a[$c]);
    @q = split (/\t/, $a[$c]);
    $qok = $q[0]."\t".$q[1];
    $qko = $q[1]."\t".$q[0];

    for ($t=0; $t<=$#f; $t++) {
        chomp ($f[$t]);
        ($id, $pf1, $pf2) = split (/\t/, $f[$t]);
        $pf_12 = $pf1."\t".$pf2;
        $pf_21 = $pf2."\t".$pf1;

        if ((($qok ne $pf_12) && ($qko ne $pf_12)) || (($qok ne $pf_21) && ($ko ne $pf_21))){
            print "$id\t$pf1\t$pf2\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem of this code is something in looping that make me obtain a wrong result and not the desired one.

Any suggestion is very welcome!

Comment: `grep -v -f file1 file2` Or something like that? And oh my gosh, those variable names of yours are confusing. How can you stand it? `$qok $qko $c $q $pf1 $pf2 $pf_12 $pf_21`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really easy to do with `grep`, if you're so inclined:

```
$ grep -Fvf b.txt a.txt
4 E F
5 G H
6 I L
```

`-F` means "fixed strings", `-v` means "invert matches", `-f` means "read patterns from file, one per line".

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to achieve this is to store the second file in a *hash*:

```
open my $ALL, '<', $file_2 or die "$file_2 : $!";

my %hash;
while (<$ALL>) {
    chomp;
    $hash{$_} = 1;
}

open my $FUS, '<', $file_1 or die "$file_1 : $!";
while (<$FUS>) {
    my ($columns) = / (.*)/;
    print unless exists $hash{$columns};
}
```

Comment: `undef $hash{$_}`? That is an unusual way to mark something as existing.

Comment: @TLP: It just creates the key without any value. In older versions of Perl, it also made the hash smaller.

Comment: Yes, I understand the principle, but perhaps readability is preferable to a minor optimization in this case.

Comment: @Gabelins: If your input files use the tab instead of space, you have to adjust the regex (use `/\t(.*)/` or `/\s(.*)/` etc.)

Comment: @choroba even if I use the "correct" whitespace character I don't get any result

Comment: @Gabelins: Is there the same whitespace in both the files?

Comment: @Gabelins: A version which should work even for different whitespace: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3GhusLWF-s

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34906/discussion-between-gabelins-and-choroba)

Answer (score 1):

If your files aren't too large, I suggest the use of hashes:

1) Fill %hash_a using as keys the required match part of the string. After read the file, this hash will have this contents:

```
%hash_a = (
'A A' => '1 A A',
'A B' => '2 A B',
...
'I L' => '6 I L'
);
```

2) Iterate on the second file, and delete from %hash_a the proper key:

```
$key =<$file>;
chomp $key;
delete $hash_a{$key};
```

3) print the remaining keys on %hash_a

Also, I recommend you:

- put this at the beginning of your script:

> ```
> use strict;
> use warnings;
> ```

- Use a modern approach to handle files:

> ```
> open my $FUS, '<', $file_1 or die "Cannot open $file_1: $!";
> ```